# VisualStates ToggleButton not working correctly

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a default style for my ToggleButtons using the VisualStateManager

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard Duration="0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PageBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonTextColor}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard Duration="0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonCheckedThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PageBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundEllipse" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Unfortunately the change works only once and the state change to checked is not triggered when checking the togglebutton but when the mouse leaves the button after it was checked.

I have tried using the same storyboard I use in "normal" also for the "Unchecked" state.
Earlier I also used the "PointerOver" and "Pressed" states but they completely messed it up because in the end it stayed in the "Pressed" state instead of the "Checked" and sometimes it did totally random changes like applying only half of a style.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong and how do I use the VisualStates correctly?

Bonusquestion: How do I tell the "PointerOver" state that it should only apply if the CheckState is "Unchecked"?

Comment: Sidenote: The 'duration="0"' and 'RepeatBehavior="Forever"' attributes were just testing.

Comment: Pull that stuff out of `Normal` and just apply it to your objects directly. For reference compare what you're doing to an actual [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709930.aspx) and you'll probably notice your folly pretty quick, if not we can come back and I'll walk ya through it. Cheers

Comment: @Stefan could you add the answer to this.

Comment: I'm not sure. It has been a while. Not that nooby anymore. But I think I just did what Chris said and removed the content from the Normal state and applied it directly to the elements since it's kinda stupid to apply transformations in the default state since it is the _default_ state.
I can check if I still have that code though if you want an answer for the sake of having an answer.